# How to properly include $ variable in icalcs PS command

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to change permissions to a users home folder by running

```
icacls $folder /grant corp.commonwealth.com\"$folder":(OI)(CI)F /t
```

Where $folder is the username of the person.

I keep getting the error

```
OI : The term 'OI' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

What is the best way to include the $folder variable while still having the :(OI)(CI)F options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve this by doing the following:

```
$username = get-content T:\userlist.txt
$icacls = "C:\Windows\system32\icacls.exe"

&$icacls $username /grant domain\"$username"":(OI)(CI)F /t"
```